# Traveling from IKA airport to Zanjan, Iran

Tags: airport-transfer, iran

I would like to know the best possible way to reach the Institute for Advanced Studies in Basic Sciences in Zanjan, from Tehran Imam Khomeini International Airport. I am a tourist who knows English language only. In particular I would like to know the nearest bus station to the airport and how to reach there. Moreover do I have to book bus tickets online?  If yes, from which site? Can I pay through credit card?